# Align two rows only using \phantom command

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical-alignment, matrices, phantom

I want to achieve the following picture:

[image: What I want]

What I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
\phantom{(n+{}}2^3-1^3\phantom{{}-1)^3}&=&3\times1^2&+&3\times1&+&1\\
\phantom{(n+{}}3^3-2^3\phantom{{}-1)^3}&=&3\times2^2&+&3\times2&+&1\\
\phantom{(n+{}}4^3-3^3\phantom{{}-1)^3}&=&3\times3^2&+&3\times3&+&1\\
\phantom{(n+{}}\vdots\phantom{{}-{}}\vdots\phantom{{}-1)^3}&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots\\
\phantom{(n+{}}n^3-(n-1)^3&=&3(n-1)^2&+&3(n-1)&+&1\\
(n+1)^3-n^3\phantom{{{}^3}-1)^3}&=&3n^2&+&3n&+&1\\\hline
(n+1)^3-1^3\phantom{{{}^3}-1)^3}&=&3(\sum_{i=1}^ni^2)&+&3(\sum_{i=1}^ni)&+&n\\
&=&3(\sum_{i=1}^ni^2)&+&\dfrac{3n(n+1)}{2}&+&n\\
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

I think it's pretty well, however if we zoom on `n^3-(n-1)^3` and `(n+1)^3-n^3` we can see they are not perfectly aligned:

[image: Not aligned]

I can't imagine another `expr` in `\phantom{expr}` than the one I put in the code:

- Before `-` sign: Since the longest expression is `(n+1)^3` and I have `n^3`, the space that compensates I think it should be `(n+{}` so `\phantom{(n+{}}`.
- After `-` sign: Since the longest expression is `(n-1)^3` and I have `n^3`, the space that compensates I think it should be `{{}^3}-1)^3` so `\phantom{{{}^3}-1)^3}`.

What should be the 2 expressions that must go in `\phantom`?

P.S. I know I could go for adding `&` before and after `-` sign, but I think it is a better approach using `\phantom`. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that phantoms are a better approach.

Comment: @egreg Hello! Long time no see you. Would you go for `&`? There are not many options left knowing that it must be written in MathJax. Thanks!

Comment: you are already using an alignment so certainly using `&` is more natural than faking alignment with `\phantom`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi David! Long time no see you. That would be a solution, but it generates a lot of extra space... The space surrounding the minus sign would be highly modified, which I think is worse aesthetically than doing 200% zoom. I would like to know what the correct spacing should be, if it is possible to calculate knowing the expressions involved.

Comment: no you shoud use alignat not matrix as this is a display it will not add space

Comment: Ok, that's another solution I will look for, thanks! What should be the correct `\phantom`s that I am not being able to achieve?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a few instructions to make your code snippet minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

Comment: You can also use \mathmakebox and \mathclap (mathtools package) to align expresstions.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the suggestion! I know about `\mathclap` (I asked some time ago about aligning expressions), however I would like to know why my `\phantom`s are not correct.

Comment: It is not so matter of correct as easy.  In fact, \mathclap together with \phantom is proabably the easiest to figure out (but not to type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the best approach. Add alignment points and let TeX do the spacing.

In the second realization I compressed the spaces and made a few cosmetic changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  r
  @{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}
  l
  c
  c
  c
  c
  c
  c
  @{}
}
2^3     &-& 1^3     &=& 3\times1^2 &+& 3\times1 &+& 1 \\
3^3     &-& 2^3     &=& 3\times2^2 &+& 3\times2 &+& 1 \\
4^3     &-& 3^3     &=& 3\times3^2 &+& 3\times3 &+& 1 \\[-0.6ex]
\vdots  & & \vdots  & & \vdots     & & \vdots   & & \vdots \\[0.2ex]
n^3     &-& (n-1)^3 &=& 3(n-1)^2   &+& 3(n-1)   &+& 1 \\
(n+1)^3 &-& n^3     &=& 3n^2       &+& 3n       &+& 1 \\
\midrule[1pt]
(n+1)^3 &-& 1^3     &=& 3(\sum_{i=1}^ni^2) &+& 3(\sum_{i=1}^ni)   &+& n \\
\addlinespace
        & &         &=& 3(\sum_{i=1}^ni^2) &+& \dfrac{3n(n+1)}{2} &+& n
\end{array}
\]

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{
  r
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  l
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
}
2^3     &-& 1^3     &=& 3\times1^2 &+& 3\times1 &+& 1 \\
3^3     &-& 2^3     &=& 3\times2^2 &+& 3\times2 &+& 1 \\
4^3     &-& 3^3     &=& 3\times3^2 &+& 3\times3 &+& 1 \\[-0.6ex]
\vdots  & & \vdots  & & \vdots     & & \vdots   & & \vdots \\[0.2ex]
n^3     &-& (n-1)^3 &=& 3(n-1)^2   &+& 3(n-1)   &+& 1 \\
(n+1)^3 &-& n^3     &=& 3n^2       &+& 3n       &+& 1 \\
\midrule[1pt]
(n+1)^3 &-& 1^3 &=&
  \displaystyle 3\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\biggr) &+&
  \displaystyle 3\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^ni\biggr) &+& n \\
\addlinespace
  && &=&
  \displaystyle 3\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\biggr) &+& \dfrac{3n(n+1)}{2} &+& n
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico No, I just forgot to remove them.